# EWS Get organizer email from GetUserAvailabilityRequest

Tags: xml, soap, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm calling EWS and requesting the User Availability of a room. My response looks like this

```
<CalendarEvent>
   <StartTime>2015-01-27T16:00:00</StartTime>
   <EndTime>2015-01-27T17:00:00</EndTime>
   <BusyType>Busy</BusyType>
   <CalendarEventDetails>
      <ID>0000000001FC1580D0DA344...</ID>
      <Subject>John Doe</Subject>
      <Location>room-d2-2pers</Location>
      <IsMeeting>true</IsMeeting>
      <IsRecurring>false</IsRecurring>
      <IsException>false</IsException>
      <IsReminderSet>false</IsReminderSet>
      <IsPrivate>false</IsPrivate>
   </CalendarEventDetails>
</CalendarEvent>
```

I can see who booked the room and I can see an ID of the meeting. I would like to get the email of the Subject, which has booked the room. I've tried a GetItem request with the ID, but I get an error stating the ID is malformed. How do I get the email of the Subject? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the ItemId your trying to use that is the HexEntryId (PR_EntryId Property) of the appointment so if you do want to bind to the Calendar Item (and you have the rights to do so) you would need to covert it to an EWSId first eg

```
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
  <m:ConvertId DestinationFormat="EwsId">
    <m:SourceIds>
      <t:AlternateId Format="HexEntryId" Id="00000000BE1CDD3D9606274890F3DE4B7DDFB....." Mailbox="mailbox@blah.com" />
    </m:SourceIds>
  </m:ConvertId>
</soap:Body>
```

Cheers
Glen

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, I think you're asking if you can find the email address of the user name that's in the subject of the event. Have you tried the [ResolveNames operation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn645423(v=exchg.150).aspx#sectionSection1)?

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't a way for you to look up the message invite from the event.  Can you please explain your scenario as to why you need to look up the invitation message?  Maybe we can provide an alternate way to implement your scenario.